# Given two subspaces $U,W$ of vector space $V$, how to show that $\dim(U)+\dim(W)=\dim(U+W)+\dim(U\cap W)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $U,W$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Show that
>   $$\dim(U)+\dim(W)=\dim(U+W)+\dim(U\cap W)$$
>   *Hint*: Show that the map given by $L:U×W\to V$ given by $L(u,w)=u-w$ is linear.

I can show that $L:U×W\to V$ given by $L(u,w)=u-w$ is a linear map. I also know that the dimension of $U×W$ is $\dim(U)+\dim(W)$. What do I do next? Any hints?

Comment: Show that $\text{Dim}(U+W)= \text{Dim}( U) + \text{Dim} (W) -\text{Dim} ( U \cap W)$.

Comment: Isn't that same? I think Dimension of $u-w$(image of map), will be $\text{Dim}(U+W)$, will the dimension of kernel of transformation will have $\text{Dim}(U\cap W) $ ??

Comment: You're on the right track. What are the nullspace and the range of $L$? Then conclude with the rank-nullity theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

Comment: @julien am I right?? will they share the same null space?

Comment: Share? There's only one map here. Its range is $L+W$. Its nullspace is isomorphic to $L\cap W$.

Comment: thanks!! i see ... the reason why $u-w$ was given instead of $u+w$

Comment: Note that the map $(u,w)\longmapsto u+w$ would have worked too.

Comment: @julien try adding your comment as answer.

Comment: I'm positive this is a duplicate but I can't find the duplicate :(

Comment: If one knows the formula for the dimension of the quotient space, all one has to do, is to show that the canonical map $T : U \longrightarrow \frac {U + W} {W}$ defined by $x \mapsto x + W,$ is a linear surjection with kernel $U \cap W.$ Once we show that we are done by the virtue of first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The range of the map $L$ is clearly $U+W$.

Now the nullspace is:
$$
\mbox{Ker} \;L=\{(u,w)\;;\; u=w\in U\cap W\}
$$
so it is isomorphic to $U\cap W$ via the map $v\longmapsto (v,v)$.

By the rank-nullity theorem applied to $L$, we find:
$$
\mbox{rank}\;L+\mbox{null}\;L=\mbox{dim}\;(U\times W)
$$
which yields the desired formula, which is sometimes called Grassmann formula..

Answer (score 5):

Hint: assume  $\dim  ( U \cap W)=k$ and let  $B_{ ( U \cap W)}={[x_1,...x_k]}$ then expand this base for W and U  let these base are  $$B_U={[x_1,...x_k,y_1,..,y_n]}$$  $$B_w={[x_1,...x_k,z_1,..,z_m]}$$ then prove C={$x_1,...x_k$,$y_1$,..,$y_n$,$z_1$,..,$z_m$} is base for W+U you can show C generate W+U and C is independent.

Comment: i thought about it too, but this is a bit awkward (since i was working on linear transformation than vector spaces). thanks anyway!!

Comment: @testuser How exactly do you claim that this is awkward? This is the most straightforward way to solve it.

Comment: @DoctorBatmanGod context :P

Answer (score 0):

Does the following suffice to prove it?

If we proceed to show the symmetric differences:

$dim(U \times W) = [ dim(U \setminus W) + dim(U \cap W) ] + [ dim(W \setminus U) + dim(U \cap W) ] $,

And we have:

$dim(U \oplus W) = dim(U \setminus W) + dim(W \setminus U) + dim(U \cap W)$

Thus,

$dim(U \times W) = dim(U \oplus W) + dim(U \cap W)$

Answer (score 0):

By the second isomorphism theorem for vector spaces, $U/(U\cap W)\cong U+W/W$. For any finite dimensional vector space U with a subspace W, $\dim U/W =\dim U-\dim W$, which is clear if one takes a basis for U: $\{u_1,...,u_r,u_{r+1},...,u_n\}$ where $u_1,...,u_r$ form a basis of W. Then $\dim U-\dim (U\cap W)=\dim(U+W)-\dim W,$ which implies $\dim(U)+\dim(W)=\dim(U+W)+\dim(U\cap W)$.