# Intersection of two three-dimensional subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $S$ and $T$ be three-dimensional subspaces of $\Bbb R^4$. 
Does it follow that $\dim(S \cap T ) \geq  2$?

Intuitively I would say yes, but its unclear how that could be proven? 
What would be a good way to approach this proof?

Comment: Use the rank+nullity theorem.  Note that $S\oplus T$ is $6$-dimensional, and $(s,t)\mapsto s - t$ is linear.  Since the kernel of this map contains at least $S\cap T$ and the image is at most $4$-dimensional, you get what you want.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1918838 gives a pretty simple proof for $\text{dim}(U) + \text{dim}(W) = \text{dim}(U + W) + \text{dim}(U \cap W)$. So $3 + 3 -  \text{dim}(U + W) = \text{dim}(U \cap W)$. And $ \text{dim}(U + W)  \le 4 \implies \text{dim}(U \cap W) \ge 2$

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality we can represent the intersection of the two subspace with a system of the form:
$$
\begin{cases}
s_1x+s_2y+s_3z+u=0\\
t_1x+t_2y+t_3z+u=0
\end{cases}
$$
that gives the solution:
$$
(s_1-t_1)x+(s_2-t_2)y+(s_3-t_3)z=0
$$
and this is the equation of a subspace of dimension at least $2$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{s_1,s_2,s_3\}$, $\{t_1,t_2,t_3\}$, $\{s_4\}$ and $\{t_4\}$ be bases for $S,T,S^\perp$ and $T^\perp$ respectively.  $S^\perp + T^\perp$ is spanned by $\{s_4,t_4\}$, so $\dim(S^\perp+T^\perp) \le 2$ and $\dim((S^\perp+T^\perp)^\perp) \ge 2$.

It remains to show $(S^\perp+T^\perp)^\perp \subseteq S \cap T$.  Let $v \in (S^\perp+T^\perp)^\perp$.  Then for all $a,b \in \Bbb{R}$, $\langle as_4+bt_4, v \rangle = 0$.  In particular, let $b = 0$ (resp. $a = 0$) so that $v \in (S^\perp)^\perp$ (resp. $v \in (T^\perp)^\perp$).  Since $S$ and $T$ are finite dimensional, $S = (S^\perp)^\perp$ and $T = (T^\perp)^\perp$.  Therefore, $v \in S$ and $v \in T$, and $\dim(S \cap T) \ge \dim((S^\perp+T^\perp)^\perp) \ge 2$.