# $\operatorname{dim}(W_1\cap W_2)\le n$ so $\operatorname{dim}(W_1\cap W_2)≤\operatorname{dim}(W_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$ having dimensions $m$ and $n$, respectively, where $m\ge n$.

$(a)$ Prove that $\operatorname{dim}(W_1 \cap W_2)≤n$

$(b)$ Prove that $\operatorname{dim}(W_1+W_2) \leq m+n$

For $(a)$ I have:
$1.  (W_1\cap W_2)$ is a subspace of $W_1$ and $W_2$
so $\operatorname{dim}(W_1\cap W_2)\le \operatorname{dim}(W_2)=n$

or

$2.$ The conclusion is $W_1 \cap W_2 \subseteq W_2$

Comment: For a) 1) is correct.
For b) see this: [grassmann formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289971/given-two-subspaces-u-w-of-vector-space-v-how-to-show-that-dimu-dimw/289986#289986)

Comment: You have to state your question clearly, do you want us to check your proof? Are you stuck somewhere? Also, learn [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) to type maths.

Comment: Thanks @polbos.

Comment: And for (a) 1.- I would like to know how the proof came to  dim(W1∩W2)≤dim(W2)=n @SiongThyeGoh  Because if 1.- is correct we can forget about 2.-

Answer (score 0):

Hint for part b:

- Starting from the basis of $W_1 \cap W_2$, extend it to a basis of $W_i$, call it $B_i$. Try to construct a set that can span $W_1+W_2$ using $B_i$.

Remark: about your second approach, the conclusion is $W_1 \cap W_2 \subseteq W_2$? That is the reason for your first approach.